# Setting frame of CCTexture to fit into a predefined frame CCSprite

Tags: iphone, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I am downloading an image from server and displaying it on game scene. I am able to get the CCTexture2D of the image from server and display it on game scene. The problem is that the image from server may vary in size. But I have to display that image on to a predefined frame CCSprite.

```
CCSprite *temp = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] resolutionType:kCCResolutioniPhoneFourInchDisplay]];
CCRenderTexture *test=[CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:70 height:70];   //set proper width and height
[test begin];
[temp draw];
[test end];
UIImage *img=[test getUIImageFromBuffer];
sprite_Temp =[CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:img.CGImage key:@"1"];
sprite_Temp.tag = K_TagUserImage;
sprite_Temp.scale=1;
sprite_Temp.position=ccp(432,273);
[self addChild:sprite_Temp z:1];
```

I am using this code to resize the CCTexture2D to predefined frame CCSprite. But the image gets cropped to the desired frame which is not wanted. Can someone tell me how to get the original image from server to desired frame without getting cropped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 CCSprite *temp = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] resolutionType:kCCResolutioniPhoneFourInchDisplay]];
float scaleX = 70./temp.contentSize.width;
float scaleY = 70./temp.contentSize.height;
// if you want to preserve the original texture's aspect ratio
float scale = MIN(scaleX,scaleY);
temp.scale = scale;
// or if you want to 'stretch-n-squeeze' to 70x70
temp.scaleX = scaleX;
temp.scaleY = scaleY;
// then add the sprite *temp
```

usual disclaimer : not tested, done from memory, beware of divides by 0 :)